# ldd command libasan not showing

Tags: shared-libraries, address-sanitizer

I have a binary in my dev machine ldd command doesn't show libasan. But when I copy the same binary to another production machine. ldd command shows libasan. I am not sure How this happens. Please help me.

```html
## DEV VM ##
cohesity - main: ldd <path>  | grep -i asan
cohesity - main: md5sum <path>
11152b37c616555eed06800ee499323a <path>
### Production machine ##
[support@suresh-test-005056af8cb9-node-1 ~]$ md5sum <path>
11152b37c616555eed06800ee499323a  <path>
[support@suresh-test-005056af8cb9-node-1 ~]$ ldd <path>  | grep -i asan
        libasan.so.4 => <path to libasan> (0x00007f72595e7000)
[support@suresh-test-005056af8cb9-node-1 ~]$
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure How this happens.

The `ldd` command output depends on a few things:

1. the binary you give it
2. all the shared libraries this binary depends on, recursively
3. local system configuration (for search paths, any `preload` libraries, etc.)

By copying the main binary to a different machine, you only guaranteed that "step 1" is identical.

Chances are that one of the shared libraries in "step 2" has been built with `-fsanitize=address` on `node-1`, but not in "dev VM".

You can find out which library that is by using `readelf -d /path/to/foo.so | grep NEEDED.*libasan.so.4` on each of the libraries in `ldd` output.